# Check is instance method is called from a constructor

Tags: java, debugging, assertions

I would like to check, from an instance method of a non-final class, whether the constructors and initializers of that class and its chain of subclasses for the specific instance have already completed.

In the following example, I have a class `Abstract`, which can be used to implement an interface which allows listeners to be added (which, for simplicity, are just `Runnable` instances here) and which provides a method `signalEvent()` which calls all attached listeners.

```
abstract class Abstract {
    protected final void signalEvent() {
        // Check that constructs have run and call listeners.
    }

    public final void addListener(Runnable runnable) {
        ...
    }
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
    Concrete() {
        // Should not call signalEvent() here.
    }

    void somethingHappened() {
        // May call signalEvent() here.
    }
}
```

Now it is possible to call `signalEvent()` from within the subclass constructor, but there is no way that a listener has already been added by that time and the event would just be lost. In our code-base, once in a while, someone adds such a call and I would like to be able to catch such calls as early as possible (using an `assert` statement or similar).

Is it possible to check whether an instance method is being called, directly or indirectly, from the subclass constructor or initializer of the current instance or, alternatively, is it possible to check whether all constructors for an instance have been completed?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set a boolean setupDone in the super constructor and check if in signalEvent?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your requirement and problem don't match... Even if `signalEvent()` is called after all constructors have returned, there is an equal chance that **NO** listeners are added. How are you handling this case? IMHO, it would be much simpler to check if there is a listener added or not.

Comment: @tobad357 That boolean would be set before the subclass constructor would run. Thus I could not detect a call to `signalEvent()` from the subclass constructor.

Comment: @Codebender You are right. Events can be missed after the constructors have run when no listeners are attached. The difference is that _if_ a listener is going to be attached, in our use cases, it is almost always done right after constructing the instance. OTOH, there are "valid" cases in our project where no listeners at all are being attached to an instance and that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there is no elegant Java mechanism that allows you to do that, but you may consider using a factory pattern. Instead of creating instances directly using `new` keyword, you could create a factory class, that takes care of creating the actual instance and invokes an additional "post-create" method, that lets the instance know it's been completely created.

If you're using some dependency injection like spring, you get that out of the box, but if not, a solution could look something like this:

```
interface PostConstruct { // the classes need to implement that
    void postConstruct();
}

public class InstanceFactory {
    public <T extends PostConstruct> T create(Class<T> clazz, Object... params) {
        T instance = //create using reflection
        instance.postConstruct();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, on second thought, technically, there is a way to achieve just what you're asking, that is to check from what context your code is called using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and examining the stack trace content, but I would not recommend that for performance reasons and most of all because it would make your code unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the problem to see if a method or code is being called from a constructor. The code below will print true and false respectivly but would be slow and not pretty at all.

I still believe it is not the right solution for the problem above. As Codbender said, better to check if a listener has been added or set a status variable which would be faster

Edit - fixed the issue that Codebender mentioned and also made sure to check back in the stack trace incase of being called a couple of methods deep

```
public class TestClass extends TestAbstract {

    public TestClass() throws Exception {
       submethod();
    }

    public void submethod() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(isInConstructor());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new TestClass().isInConstructor());
    }

}

public class TestAbstract {

    public boolean isInConstructor() throws Exception {
        StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement element : elements) {
            if (element.getMethodName().equals("<init>") &&
                TestAbstract.class.isAssignableFrom(Class.forName(element.getClassName()))) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: There are many problems with this method... Eg: This will return true if you call the method from any constructor (not necessarily of the instance object's).

Comment: Very true, didn't check to much as I don't really want to encourage this at all.. now I've spend way to much time on it :)